# AngularJS select with Zurb Foundation Custom Forms

Tags: angularjs, zurb-foundation

I recently started a project with Zurb Foundation where I create dynamic select form fields with AngularJS.

The example at http://jsbin.com/egizel/1/edit works except if I want to use Zurb Foundation's Custom Forms.  To activate it, I understand I have to replace `<form>` with `<form class="custom">`, but when I do, the dynamic select field created with AngularJS stops working. The static select field is not affected.

Is it possible to work with AngularJS and Zurb Foundation's Custom Forms? How to fix this simple example?

Answer (score 1):

This solved it for me, but I feel this is not the angular way though..

```
angular.module('someApp', [''])
  .run(function($rootScope) {
      $("select").bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function() {
          Foundation.libs.forms.refresh_custom_select($("select"), true);
      });
  })
```

Comment: This won't work if your `select` is loaded via a route into an `ngView`  I think you're better off listening for the `$viewContentLoaded` event for items rendered in the `ngView`

Answer (score 0):

When you activate custom forms in foundation, the javascript modifies your select element and gives it a style of display:none. The select element is then replaced by a visible div class="custom dropdown".  Everything you do in angularjs code is lost.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that. Do you know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a solution, but I found a very simple workaround. Just apply this CSS to the select field:

```
select {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  height: 2.3125em;
  margin-bottom: 1.25em;
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  font-size: 0.875em;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

Althought not a real solution, it does solve my problem where the form looked wierd when mixing styled input fields with non styled select fields. I wish this would be the default behavior in Zurb Foundation.

Answer (score 0):

Add this jQuery code to your js file:

```
$("#my_select").bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function() {
    $(document).foundation("forms");    
});
```

This will execute the foundation script for custom forms after each change AngularJS will do in the select-option DOM.

The only problem with this solution is when you change the model via js - the display value on  the foundation select - not change.

To solve it I add $watch to this model in my AngularJS controller - and change the display value manually.
For example: (my model is 'selected')

```
$scope.$watch('selected', function() {
    if($scope.selected) //only after AngularJS initial it
        $('#myselect + .custom.dropdown a.current').text($scope.selected);
    $('#my_form').show() // optional - see below ...
});
```

I hide the form and show it here - to prevent bad gui in the way...

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't understand how to apply your solution. It would be great if you could fix this simple example at http://jsbin.com/egizel/1/edit

Comment: Why don't you save your list in ng-controller ? I tried to fit the solution to your case : http://jsbin.com/egizel/12/edit

Comment: I think the "undefined" is caused by some other problem... I don't know if it's related to my question. I'm really confused right now. I tried creating other examples at jsbin.com and they always shows as "undefined". I don't know what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You or someone else will probably need to start a project to create directives for Foundation classes much like Angular-UI (http://angular-ui.github.io/) and Angular-UI-Bootstrap (http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)

Answer (score -3):

There are a lot of conflicts between AngularJs and zurb foundation .

I suggest to leave zurb foundation and try use in bootstrap

see link : http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/